# Mover Las Islas Canarias y aproximar a la península en un mapa ggplot con r y sf

Tags: r, ggplot2

He intentado mover las geometrías de Las Islas Canarias hacia la península para que el mapa de España se vea en una escala mayor para representar información por provincias.

He partido del fichero shapefile de esta ubicación ESRI

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=83d81d9336c745fd839465beab885ab7

El código utilizado es este, se necesita `ggplot2` y `sf`

```
geoprovincias <- st_read("ruta/Provincias_ETRS89_30N.shp")

geopenínsula <- geoprovincias[!geoprovincias$CCAA=="Canarias",]
geocanarias <- geoprovincias[geoprovincias$CCAA=="Canarias",]

crs <- st_crs(geopenínsula)

geocanariasco <- geocanarias %>% 
 st_transform(crs) %>%
 st_geometry()
geocanariasco <- geocanariasco + c(5, 7)

geocanarias <- geocanarias %>% 
 st_set_geometry(geocanariasco) %>%
 st_set_crs(crs)

geoprovincias <- rbind(geopenínsula, geocanarias)

mprovincias <- geoprovincias %>% 
 ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
   fill="white",
   color="#1D1D1D",
   size=0.5
  ) +
 theme_void()
mprovincias
```

Comment: Ëchale un vistazo al paquete `mapSpain`, lo hace por defecto: https://ropenspain.github.io/mapSpain/reference/esp_get_can_box.html

Comment: Ejemplo aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510339/representaci%c3%b3n-mapas-discontinuos-en-r

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido resolver desde una fuente distinta,

http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/index.jsp

Siguiendo los enlaces: Información geográfica de referencia - Límites municipales, provinciales y autonómicos - Descargar: lineas_limite.zip.

En la carpeta descomprimida tenemos los shapefile que vamos a utilizar: SIGLIM_Publico_INSPIRE:

- SHP_ETRS89 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp
- SHP_WGS84 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84 - recintos_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84.shp

```
library(sf)
library(rmapshaper)
library(ggplot2)

geopropenínsula <- st_read("ruta/recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp")
geoprocanarias <- st_read("ruta/recintos_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84.shp")

crs <- st_crs(geopropenínsula) #CRS Península, Baleares, Ceuta y Melilla

geoprocanariasco <- geoprocanarias %>% 
 st_transform(crs) %>% #Transformamos las geometrías de Canarias
 st_geometry() #Extraemos las geometrías.

geoprocanariasco <- geoprocanariasco + c(5, 7) #Movemos Canarias

geoprocanarias <- geoprocanarias %>% 
 st_set_geometry(geoprocanariasco) %>%  #Cambiamos las geometrías de Canarias
 st_set_crs(crs) #Volvemos a especificar el CRS de la Península para Canarias.

geoprovincias <- rbind(geopropenínsula, geoprocanarias) #Unimos

# Eliminamos el territorio no asociado a ninguna provincia.
geoprovincias <- geoprovincias[!geoprovincias$CódigoProvincia=="54",]

# Simplificamos los límites provinciales.
geosprovincias <- ms_simplify(geoprovincias, keep = 0.00050, weighting = 6)

mapapro <- geosprovincias %>%
 ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```