# Representación mapas discontinuos en R

Tags: r

Me gustaría añadir datos numéricos en el mapa de España. El problema que tengo es que las islas canarias se me salen fuera del mapa.
Para ello he echado mano de grid.arrange pero no se superponen las imagenes y por lo tanto no me quedan como me gustaría:

Partiendo de esta base de datos:

```
    mortalidad<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(
    comunidad   sum_2020    Per_2020
    Andalucía   6517    8.70802656369005
    Aragón  2942    3.93110543967717
    Canarias    501 0.669437058218309
    Cantabria   495 0.661419847940245
    Castilla - La Mancha    6500    8.68531113456887
    Castilla y León 7712    10.3047876107377
    Cataluña    15884   21.2242280094603
    Ceuta   63  0.0841807079196676
    Comunidad de Madrid 19357   25.8648565587461
    Comunidad Foral de Navarra  1183    1.58072662649153
    Comunidad Valenciana    3812    5.09360092999639
    Extremadura 1389    1.85598417937172
    Galicia 1582    2.11387110998276
    Islas Baleares  600 0.801721027806358
    La Rioja    648 0.865858710030866
    Melilla 47  0.062801480511498
    País Vasco  3064    4.09412204866447
    Principado de Asturias  1773    2.36908563716779
    Región de Murcia    770 1.02887531901816),ncol=3,byrow = TRUE))
```

Quiero incorporar estos datos al mapa de españa
Para ello me he descargado el mapa de españa en formato shp:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnINhMxGBW4rBYnfqFHjLiOpYf9AYtkQ/view?usp=sharing

Leo el achivo shp:

```
     españa_d <- st_read("Comunidades_Autonomas_ETRS89_30N.shp") 
     
    españa_d <- españa_d %>% mutate(centroid = map(geometry, st_centroid), 
                        coords = map(centroid,st_coordinates), 
                        coords_x = map_dbl(coords, 1), 
                        coords_y = map_dbl(coords,2))

              españa_d$mortalidad<-pobreza$Per_2020[match(españa_d$Texto,pobreza$comunidad)]


      mprovincias_1<-ggplot(españa_d%>%
              filter(Texto!="Canarias")) +
       geom_sf(aes(fill = mortalidad))+
       labs(title = "Porcentaje de mortalidad por COVID-19 (2020)",
            x="Longitud",
            y="Latitud")+
       theme_minimal() +
       scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("blue","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                            breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100),labels=c("0%","25%","50%","75%","100%"),
                            limits=c(0,100))+
       geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(coords_x, coords_y, label = Texto), size = 3.5,fontface="bold")

     mprovincias_2 <-  
       ggplot(españa_d%>%
                filter(Texto=="Canarias")) +
       geom_sf(aes(fill=mortalidad))+
       theme_minimal() +
       scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("blue","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                            breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100),labels=c("0%","25%","50%","75%","100%"),
                            limits=c(0,100))+
       geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(coords_x, coords_y, label = Texto), size = 3.5,fontface="bold")


     grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(mprovincias_1, mprovincias_2, ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                              heights = c(2, 1)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría mover las islas canarias a la península de una manera proporcional?

He probado este link https://github.com/Nowosad/spain-map-layout/blob/master/R/03_third_approach.R

Pero como no parto con los datos brutos me quedo atacado en esta parte:

```
     # create breaks -----------------------------------------------------------
     breaks = classInt::classIntervals(all_data$X2017, n = 5, style = "quantile")

     # add breaks to data ------------------------------------------------------
     all_data$X2017_breaks = cut(all_data$X2017, breaks$brks, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Como solución rápida yo probaría con el facetado de Ggplot, sino, lo otro es "mover" geográficamente las islas más cerca del continente, algo como esto: https://github.com/Nowosad/spain-map-layout

Comment: @Patricio Moracho me gustaría mover las islas más cerca del contienente, he visto que tmap puede ser una buena alternativa,  me gustaría saber como realizarlo mediante mi ggplot

Comment: El enlace que te pasé tiene una alternativa usando ggplot que la probé y funciona muy bien, puedo intentar responderte pero necesitaría un ejemplo reproducible, básicamente los datos de españa_df

Comment: Perdona @Patricio Moracho por la demora. He actualizado la pregunta añadiendo los datos desde lo que parto y en que parte me quedo atascado siguiendo el tutorial que me presentas. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparto aquí una solución con el paquete [mapSpain](https://ropenspain.github.io/mapSpain/), que permite desplazar Canarias de una manera sencilla:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mapSpain)
library(ggrepel)
library(sf)


mortalidad <- tribble(
  ~comunidad, ~sum_2020, ~Per_2020,
  "Andalucía", 6517, 8.70802656369005,
  "Aragón", 2942, 3.93110543967717,
  "Canarias", 501, 0.669437058218309,
  "Cantabria", 495, 0.661419847940245,
  "Castilla - La Mancha", 6500, 8.68531113456887,
  "Castilla y León", 7712, 10.3047876107377,
  "Cataluña", 15884, 21.2242280094603,
  "Ceuta", 63, 0.0841807079196676,
  "Comunidad de Madrid", 19357, 25.8648565587461,
  "Comunidad Foral de Navarra", 1183, 1.58072662649153,
  "Comunidad Valenciana", 3812, 5.09360092999639,
  "Extremadura", 1389, 1.85598417937172,
  "Galicia", 1582, 2.11387110998276,
  "Islas Baleares", 600, 0.801721027806358,
  "La Rioja", 648, 0.865858710030866,
  "Melilla", 47, 0.062801480511498,
  "País Vasco", 3064, 4.09412204866447,
  "Principado de Asturias", 1773, 2.36908563716779,
  "Región de Murcia", 770, 1.02887531901816
)

# CCAA con Canarias desplazada
ccaa <- esp_get_ccaa_siane(moveCAN = TRUE)

# Prepara cruce

mortalidad$codauto <- esp_dict_region_code(mortalidad$comunidad,
  destination = "codauto"
)

# Une

ccaa_mort <- ccaa %>% left_join(mortalidad)

# Coordenadas para las etiquetas
ccaa_mort_coords <- ccaa_mort %>%
  st_centroid(of_largest_polygon = TRUE) %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(coords_x = X, coords_y = Y) %>%
  select(coords_x, coords_y) %>%
  bind_cols(ccaa_mort, .)

# Si queremos la caja de Canarias
canarias_bbox <- esp_get_can_box(moveCAN = TRUE)


# Plot

ggplot(ccaa_mort_coords) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Per_2020)) +
  geom_sf(data = canarias_bbox, fill = NA) +
  labs(
    title = "Porcentaje de mortalidad por COVID-19 (2020)",
    x = "Longitud",
    y = "Latitud"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("blue", "red"), na.value = "transparent",
    breaks = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100), labels = c(
      "0%",
      "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"
    ),
    limits = c(0, 100)
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(coords_x,
    coords_y,
    label = comunidad
  ), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El truco en este caso es ajustar las coordenadas de las islas, para "acercarlas" más al continente. La fuente original de esta respuesta la tienes [aquí](https://github.com/Nowosad/spain-map-layout). El trabajo lo hace esta función:

```
place_geometry = function(geometry, bb, scale_x, scale_y,
                          scale_size = 1) {
  output_geometry = (geometry - st_centroid(geometry)) * scale_size +
    st_sfc(st_point(c(
      bb$xmin + scale_x * (bb$xmax - bb$xmin),
      bb$ymin + scale_y * (bb$ymax - bb$ymin)
    )))
  return(output_geometry)
}
```

En primer lugar, deberemos trabajar sobre los datos de Las Canarias:

```
españa_d %>% 
  filter(Texto == 'Canarias') %>% 
  mutate(geometry = place_geometry(geometry, st_bbox(españa_d), 0.3, 0.5)) %>% 
  st_set_crs(st_crs(españa_d)) -> canarias

canarias_bbox = st_buffer(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(canarias)), 10000)
```

Con esto hicimos dos cosas: 1) Ajustamos la posición de las islas. Los valores del ajuste son a gusto del consumidor x= 0.3, y=0.5 2) Generamos un objeto para dibujar un recuadro, algo que hace más claro que la ubicación de las islas no es la real.

Lo siguiente es unir las "nuevas Canarias" con el resto del continente y calcular, ahora las posiciones de las etiquetas en base a las nuevas coordenadas.

```
españa_d %>% 
  filter(Texto != 'Canarias') %>% 
  bind_rows(canarias) %>% 
  mutate(centroid = map(geometry, st_centroid), 
         coords = map(centroid,st_coordinates), 
         coords_x = map_dbl(coords, 1), 
         coords_y = map_dbl(coords,2)) -> plot_data
```

Lo único que resta es el gráfico en si mismo, al cual simplemente le agregamos el recuadro para las islas:

```
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = mortalidad))+
  geom_sf(data = canarias_bbox, fill = NA) +
  labs(title = "Porcentaje de mortalidad por COVID-19 (2020)",
       x="Longitud",
       y="Latitud")+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("blue","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                       breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100),labels=c("0%","25%","50%","75%","100%"),
                       limits=c(0,100))+
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(coords_x, coords_y, label = Texto), size = 3.5,fontface="bold")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explicación excelente y encima funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias de nuevo Patricio